# The Frechet derivative can be defined in 2 ways. Is there an easy way of showing that they are equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis

1. $F: X \to Y$ ($X$, $Y$ normed vector spaces) then exists a linear transformation $A:X \to Y$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ exists $\delta >0$ such that $||F(x+h)-F(x)-Ah||\leq \epsilon ||h||$
   for all $h$ such that $||h|| \leq \delta$ (1st norm belongs to $Y$, norm for  $||h||$ belongs to $X$)
2. $$F'(x)= {d \over d\epsilon} {F(x+\epsilon r}) \mid _{\epsilon = 0}$$

Comment: The former is the Frechet derivative

Comment: As usual, a context-less question doesn't have a useful answer. Who told you that these are equivalent definitions? Did they have some assumptions in place? Nobody knows.

Comment: @NormalHuman Context is a version of NLS function  from C to C.

Comment: 2nd defn. was what my supervisor said was that of Frechet derivative. 1st defn. was from Wikipedia and Wolfram cited Ostasewski 2012

Answer (score 2):

The second definition is in fact the definition of the Gateaux derivative and is a strictly weaker notion than that of a Frechet derivative. In particular, if a function is Frechet differentiable then it is also Gateaux differentiable, but the converse is not necessarily true. The Gateaux derivative may fail to be linear or continuous.